# TCPDF tablecontent

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I have an application that uses TCPDF to generate a pdf, the table content is pretty large and  the content itself will be fetched dynamically for each individual chapter.

My question is how to link the bookmark in the table of contents to the specific page of each generated chapter (the actual problem is that a chapter can span to mutiple pages, and I don't know a way on how to calculate on how many different pages that chapter spans).

I know that you can use the following code to bookmark a page, but I explained the problem above (I don't know the exact page of the chapter)

```
 $pdf->Bookmark($name, $indent, -1, $page, $indent == 0 ? $style : '', $color);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a long way around, but it's probably how I would do it.

1. Create the PDF without the table of contents
2. Parse the PDF file with [PDF parser](http://www.pdfparser.org/)
3. Create a second PDF for the table of contents using the parsed data to identify what pages the bookmarks should link to
4. Combine the two PDF's with [PDFTK](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/)

Comment: I will give it a try